# Installing a Click Once Application to another server gives a "System Update Required' error, Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient Version 11.0.0.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, installation, adomd.net

I had an application installed and running on a DEV server. I now need to install it on another server, QA, but get this error:

```
System Update Required

Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient Version 11.0.0.0 be installed into the 
Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

Please contact your system administrator.
```

I have installed the ADOMD.NET Client from the Microsoft site but still get the error. I dont think it is installing version 11. I noticed that the machines do not have the same specs, SQL 2005 on QA (target server) and SQL 2008 on the DEV server(previous install).

Does anyone know the cause of this? Do I need to upgrade to SQL 2008 on the QA server for version 11 to install? Can I add a reference in the project so its not required on the target machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution:

This project(B) was referencing another project(A) (there are about 10 projects in the solution).

The project it was referencing(A) was making use of Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient (as well as a few others) in it's references folder.

To resolve this I added the reference to the project(B) I was working on by adding them from the other project's(A) reference folder, thereby putting them in this projects(B) reference folder.

You will also need to access the properties of the newly added reference (in project B) and set 'Copy Local' to true so that it is added to the project when published, therefore not needing it installed on the target environment as it is now part of the applications setup files.

Hope that makes sense, let me know if you have a similar issue and anything is unclear :)